# Shrink btrfs from /dev/sda to /dev/sda1

Tags: filesystems, mount, partition, btrfs

suppose I have 2 btrfs filesystems:

1. one mounted on `/mnt/big` spanning across /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
2. the other mounted on `/mnt/small` on a single drive: /dev/sde

How would I shrink the btrfs filesystem lying on /dev/sde to /dev/sde1?

The reason I want to do this is that `/mnt/big` is raid1 while `/mnt/small` is not and I would like to extend `/mnt/big`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel a little like a python developer, see the https://github.com/g2p/blocks. It already does a similar stuff - shrinking a partition a few bytes off, to make a little place for bcache/lvm metadata.

If you don't - at least you can post a feature request. It should be relatively easy to add such feature to the already existing code.

Personally, I've used the blocks for bcache and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible without using another drive.

If you have all of /dev/sde under btrfs management, how would you create the partition /dev/sde1 on the drive /dev/sde without destroying the existing file system?